# Becoming the marathon "leader", is this a correct usage?

Tags: word-choice, sports, terminology

What do we call the athlete who is in first place , leading the marathon or running in front of the other runners in a race?

Is **leader** an appropriate word to describe this runner?

Answer (score 2):

You could call the athlete **the front-runner**.

Comment: Source? Always try to substantiate an answer with a reliable source of information.

Comment: ***frontrunner*** 1. One that is in a leading position in a race or other competition: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/frontrunner

Comment: The word front-runner carriers a bunch of connotations.  I don't think I would ever use it to describe the person leading a race.  That is just me though.  I would say someone is a front-runner in that they perform better when doing well or in the lead and the opposite if they are not in the lead.

Answer (score 0):

'Leader' is a perfectly acceptable word to use in UK English for the front-runner of a race.

Richard D.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with the use of front-runner here at all - at least for AE purposes.  It doesn't sound right and wouldn't be used by an announcer of a race.

In marathons or races we hear the following words:

- The lead
- the pole (especially in moto races)
- the pace(r) position
- first